# Closing JFrame => Program crashes

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have two `JFrame`s:

- `ApplicationsJFrame`, which is my Main, and
- `InsertApplicationsForm`.

I'm setting the `InsertApplicationsForm` visible by clicking a `Button` in my `ApplicationsJFrame`.

Every time I'm closing the `InsertApplicationsForm` the `ApplicationsJFrame` also closes, but the Program is still running, same when I minimize `InsertApplicationsForm`, `ApplicationsJFrame` minimizes, but wont maximize anymore...

ApplicationsJFrame:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setTitle("T-AMS");
setFocusableWindowState(false);
```

InsertApplicationsForm:

```
public class InsertApplicationForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form InsertApplicationForm
     */
    public InsertApplicationForm() {
        initComponents();
    }
```

[...]

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Insert Application")
addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowClosed(evt);
            }
        });

private void formWindowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
        ApplicationsJFrame.insert = false;
    }
```

Open `InsertApplicationsForm`:

```
new InsertApplicationForm().setVisible(true);
```

Comment: How do you create the `InsertApplicationsForm`? Do you specify the main frame as parent? Also check for any `WindowListener` or `WindowStateListener`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html

Comment: edited it. I only added some Textfields and labels since creating the Form

Comment: That's odd. If you don't pass the main frame as parent into `InsertApplicationForm`, the two frames should be completely independent; minimizing one should not affect the other. Which OS? Did you check for any Window listeners?

Comment: Just talked to a friend that i just dont get it because the frames should be independent.... -.-
OS is Windows 7

Comment: Got a listener which sets a variable in the other frame so i can check if the frame is opened..... did exactly the same in my other programs, never was a problem

Comment: Okay, I'm out of ideas. Maybe add a Window listener to the main frame to see what events it does receive; that might give you clue what is going on. You can also use `new Exception().printStackTrace();` in the event listener to see who calls the code. **Don't set breakpoints** in window listeners, your application, IDE or Windows can hang if you do.

Comment: I don't see anything here that could cause such a problem, unless `ApplicationdJFrame.insert` plays a role in the issue. Please show more code

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just add the EXIT_ON_CLOSE constant int to your main JFrame.
Instead, add a WindowListener to your temporal Frames:

```
//Suppose you have a custom Frame in your Form class
class InsertApplicationsForm extends JFrame{
//Some stuff
//...

public InsertApplicationsForm(){
//Implement
    //DO NOT ADD setDefaultCloseOperation
setVisible(true);
}

addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){

     @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        InsertApplicationsForm.this.dispose();
    }

});
```

}

So in your main class, or method, event, whatever just call this:

```
new InsertApplicationsForm();
```

And will automatically open a new JFrame, which you can close and not affecting the main or other Frames. You can even instance multiple of this class Frames and closing won't affect other ones.

Comment: Still doesnt work, i think i'll just have to rewrite the program -.-
Thanks for all your help!
I wrote a lot of programs with many different forms... never had a problem like this before...